# Isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not product of $n$ reflections

Tags: geometry

I saw that every isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is product of at most $n+1$ reflections.

**Q.** Is there isometry of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which can not be written as product of $n$ reflections?

I tried to get an example, but failed to realize it in higher dimensions. Possibly, screw motion in $\mathbb{R}^3$ may be an example, but I would like to see example in general higher dimensions also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Take $n=2$ and take isometry which is a composition of reflection and "moving" by a specific vector. Then you need $3$ reflections in order to write is a product of reflections.

Or even better, $n=1$, map
$$x\mapsto x+1$$

Comment: Yes! I understand example in low dimension (=1,2,3) case; but I don't find example in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>3$.